# Can we add standard Non-English close reason?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons

As can be observed on the [close stats](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats) page a significant number of custom close reasons is about a question being asked in a language other than English. This is currently covered by either "Needs more clarity" or a custom close reason. Could we have a site-specific standard closure message for such questions, please?

The reason why "Needs more clarity" is not enough is that quite often OP doesn't notice that they asked in the wrong language or that we even require posts to be written in English. Asking them for more details can be a little confusing. On the other hand, a custom close reason can be written in any number of ways often sounding blunt or even impolite.

It would be nice to have a standard reason that explains why we require English language and point users to sites in their local languages.

[image]

Comment: If OP doesn't notice that they're on a site for a completely different language than what they're writing in, I doubt any massaging of close reasons will help get the point across. (If anything, I'd like for first-time posters to be required to click a button: "What language is this question in" and have the question blocked and redirected if not English) It would also probably be not too hard to automatically detect and block questions that have significant non-English and lacking English phrases

Comment: @CertainPerformance Actually, pointing it out does work. I saw a number of users apologize for forgetting to translate.

Comment: I'm sure we've all thought of this, but don't think it happens often enough to ask for another standard reason in meta.

Comment: The link requires a high level of privileges and the data itself changes over time. Can you include the information you’re looking at in the post itself?

Comment: @Laurel I don't understand why that link is not accessible to all 3k+ users.

Comment: @AnnZen It happens all the time for some users, just because you don't see it doesn't mean it doesn't happen. Look at the statistics.

Comment: @Dharman:  The screencap you shared is part of the moderator tools window, which is only available to 10k+ users.

Comment: @Makoto Yes, which is odd because this has nothing to do with deleting questions. It is only stats about question closures.

Comment: ...which is useful from a moderation perspective (as in, when you have more moderation powers unlocked), not a general curation perspective.  3k+ users can be more predicated on actual question closure and 10k+ users can be predicated on how the 3k+ users (and themselves) are doing with those closures.

Comment: Is there any reason to make this new close-reason site-specific? Is this not a network wide issue?

Comment: @cigien [pt.so], [es.so], [ja.so], [ru.so]

Comment: I'm assuming your point is that other SE sites don't have many language-specific versions, so pointing users to another site is not practical? That would be an issue on SO as well, since plenty of languages don't have their own SO site either.

Comment: @10Rep If I don't see it, why would I say *I'm sure we've all thought of this*?

Comment: @AnnZen You can think something but not experience it. If you've experienced it, you wouldn't say that.

Comment: Which close reason you suggest to remove as the number of close reasons is fixed?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I did not know that. Where does it say it?

Comment: I was sure I seen it somewhere... but searching did not find official confirmation. I found a similar comment but it is all. So the restriction on number of close reasons could be just my imagination. Will try to search more later

Comment: @10Rep Hello! Please describe "all the time". My definition: stumbling upon duplicate posts.
*If you've experienced it, you wouldn't say that.* I *have* experienced it, and I've also said it, so... whoops!

Comment: in the few languages that i speak, i add a comment in the original language, which works just fine. as here are  alot of people we get all languages coveres :D

Comment: We are already at the maximum number of site-specific close reasons, and have been for many years. Thus, any new reason must replace an existing site-specific reason. As with all requests for new/additional site-specific close reasons, you need to specify which currently existing site-specific close reason should be replaced by the one you propose. In general, that means you need to demonstrate that your new proposed reason is used more often than at least one existing reason, and/or that it will be beneficial to the community to replace a current reason with the one you propose.

Comment: @Makyen Is there a reason why we can't have any more site-specific reasons? This seems like an artificial limitation.

Comment: It's the way the system is designed. As to the reasoning behind that limit, I don't recall seeing a discussion about it, but it might be mentioned in posts from many years ago during the time the site/network was more dynamic. I'd assume that at least part of the desire is that they don't want the close dialog to end up too tall. To change the limit, you would need to propose a feature request to allow a larger number of active site-specific close reasons, which I expect would be a network-wide change. You'd need an SE dev to tell you how much effort it would be.

Comment: Wow, my custom closing comments hold the positions no. 2, 3, and 4 simultaneously, with a cumulative score of 86 (plus 19 more below)! Maybe *I* should request this to be added to the standard reasons... :)

Comment: @Makyen just roll server faul and super user into one close reason, removing the references to either and then SO has a extra slot.

Comment: @Braiam Yes, that's a solution I've been considering. Basically, just make a single "Not programming as defined in the help center" reason.

Comment: @Makyen shut up and take my upvotes! BTW, where's the meta post?

Answer (score -10):

The language barrier runs in both directions.

Unless it's localized for whatever language the person happens to be posting in, there is no messaging that exists that will convey the message that their question has to be posted in English.  Worse, they may be in a position where they can't actively understand English and their language doesn't have a dedicated localized version of Stack Overflow, so they're doubly out of luck.

Closing it period is the best we can do, as we are only able to deal with the symptom of a question not in English appearing on the site.  The actual affliction is further out of reach.

I'll also add that this is something on the order of 500 closures.  We had on the order of 55,000 closures this past 30 days.  This is an "issue" that applies to a small fraction of users, and there's not enough of a compelling argument that I'm seeing that'd justify spending the time on it from a developer's perspective.

Comment: Devil's advocate: Languages can be automatically deduced (quite reliably) from sufficient corpus (see: Google Translate). A single message in a specific language (say, English) can then be automatically translated into that language with understandable results in many cases (see again: Google Translate). In other words, we could do this if we wanted to.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi:  I would not trust Google Translate to *reliably* convey localized meaning to why someone's post needs to be in English.  Furthermore, given the nuances of languages that are ambiguous in character set (thinking Chinese and Japanese here), not convinced that it'd be worth the effort.  Furthermore, we're talking about a problem that isn't all *that* common.  Less than 500 closures for a post being in a foreign language is less than 1% of all the posts that were closed in the last month.  I don't see the ROI on even relying on Google Translate to help what is a minor problem.

Comment: That's the thing, we do not need an accurate or meaningful translation, what we need is to detect whenever or not it's in English. If we can say with >90% certainty that something is English and <10% that is not English, then it's very likely to be English. We don't need to know what it is, just what it isn't.

Comment: @Braiam: No, this is incorrect.  This mentality is what brought about the notion of [Engrish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engrish), in that we have one language trying to transliterate to another language with little concern or emphasis on the message trying to be conveyed.  In other words, *just* translating it is the i18n part of the work; actually making it make sense is the l10n part of the work.  Stopping short of l10n is both a slap to the face of non-native speakers and is incredibly lazy on the part of Stack Overflow, since we want to be *crystal clear* when we say "English only".

Comment: @Makoto even "Engrish" is easily discernible to non-speakers, it's about common strings on one language.

Comment: @Braiam:  [Except it isn't.](https://www.reddit.com/r/engrish/comments/9jcinv/no_dumb_area/)  If it's not done well then you introduce *more* ambiguity.  Also don't get me started on how bad Google Translate is for certain languages (like Japanese).

Comment: Again, we don't want to translate anything at all: just answering the question "is this english?" with a yes or no response. Your argument is entirely based on a strawman, nobody here wants to translate anything, just tell them that their post is not in English.

Comment: @Braiam:  I fail to see how what I'm saying is a straw man.  If you're going to say, "This post needs to be in English" in the myriad of languages of the world, then it needs to be said clearly.  I'm not willing to agree with a half-assed approach to that, which is what I'm honing in on.

Comment: Even if it's half-assed, if it prevents 90% of the questions that are not in english from being asked in not-english that's good enough. That's 90% of questions that people don't have to waste time with.